# Outlook Add-in VSTO: Update and email, mark as unread and put it on top of inbox

Tags: c#, outlook, visual-studio-2019, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to update an Outlook.MailItem that is in my inbox.

First I search for it in the inbox. Once I have found it I copy it into another Outlook.MailItem and then I work with the copy: I update it and move it to the inbox.

Finally if it is successfull I delete the old Outlook.MailItem.

**Code**:

```
try
{
    Outlook.MailItem omi = this.SearchForMailItem(id); // this searches for an Outlook.MailItem in the inbox based on and Id.
    
    Outlook.MailItem omiCopy = omi.Copy();
    
    // Here I update the copy with some user properties
    omiCopy.SetUserProperty(myProperty, true);
    
    // I set some flags
    omiCopy.SetMessageFlag(MapiPropertyValue.EnumPidTagMessageFlags.mfUnsent, false);
    
    // Move to the inbox and save the Outlook.MailItem updated
    Outlook.MailItem omiFinal = omiCopy.Move(GetFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox));
    omiFinal.Save();
    
    omiFinal = null;
    
    // Delete the old one
    omi.Delete();
}
Catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Print error
}
```

It is not working, the old one is not deleted. So I get two emails in the inbox. Also below exception is thrown:

> Cannot move the items.

What am I doing wrong?

**What I am trying to do is**:

Update an Outlook.MailItem (email), mark it as unread and move it at the top of the inbox, like when you receive a new email. I do not know how to do this, so I did what I have posted, make a copy, update and then delete the old one.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:
I have realized the Save() before doing the Move() and I get the same exception.

Comment: Does it work if you comment out the SetMessageFlag line?

Comment: Do you get any exceptions at runtime in the code? Did you try to wrap the code with a `try/catch` block?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I get the same exception: Cannot move the items.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I have put a try-catch and I get below exception: Cannot move the items. I have updated the post.

Comment: If you just save the message, it  ends up being in the Inbox folder, right? So the error just tells you that you cannot move an item to the folder where it already resides. Does it work if you move to any other folder?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Ops, ok ok, you are right, it makes sense. Cannot move the item within the same folder, I understand (the message was a little bit confused). And do you know how can I move the updated message with a new received date in order to it appears in the inbox as the first message and marked as unread?

Comment: `ReceivedTime` is read-only in OOM. Setting `PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME` using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` also won't help - as far as I remember, OOM won't let you set that property. I can only think of using Redemption (I am its author).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to call the `Save` method before calling `Move` one.

```
Outlook.MailItem omi = this.SearchForMailItem(id); // this searches for an Outlook.MailItem in the inbox based on and Id.

Outlook.MailItem omiCopy = omi.Copy();

// Here I update the copy with some user properties
omiCopy.SetUserProperty(myProperty, true);

// I set some flags
omiCopy.SetMessageFlag(MapiPropertyValue.EnumPidTagMessageFlags.mfUnsent, false);

omiCopy.Save();

// Move to the inbox and save the Outlook.MailItem updated
Outlook.MailItem omiFinal = omiCopy.Move(GetFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox));

omiFinal = null;

// Delete the old one
omi.Delete();
```

Also I'd recommend using the [Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject?view=net-6.0) method which decrements the reference count of the Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW) associated with the specified COM object. See [Systematically releasing objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/systematically-releasing-objects) for more information. Setting the object to `null` is not enough for releasing th eunderlying COM objects in managed programming languages:

```
omiFinal = null;
```

Finally, I'd recommend using the `try/catch` to know if any errors are thrown in the code. So, wrap your code with a `try/catch` block.

Comment: I have moved Save() method before calling the Move() and I get the same exception: Cannot move the items. I have updated the post.

Comment: Have you tried to move the item to another folder? Are you able to reproduce the issue with raw OOM objects without involving your extra code? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, it works if i move to another folder different from inbox. But what i am trying to do is  to update the message (outlook mailItem), and once updated mark it as unread and change its received date in order to it appears as the first message received on the top of the inbox. How can I do this?